# Android Studio Gradle Sync Failed After Upgrading to Chipmunk 2021.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

so I upgraded my Android Studio to Chipmunk 2021.2.1 and everything was going fine, but when I try to run my app on my Pixel 5 emulator, the gradle doesn't build. It's having 18 errors under the `writeDebugSigningConfigVersions` and I need help trying to solve the issues. I tried switching the gradle offline mode to see if that would let the app run, but the errors didn't go away. What should I do to fix these issues? Is it to do with the actual gradle, or is it a setting I need to change? Thank you.

**My Gradle Errors**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out what the problem was. I implemented a dependency called `CalendarView` in my build.gradle app file that was making those errors. The answer is that I need to find a specific version of the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Without an actual stack-trace, this question only permits an educated guess.
I'd suggest to upgrade the Gradle wrapper to a compatible version; eg. `7.4.2`.
Each version of AGP has specific requirements for the Gradle version to use.

Comment: I upgraded the wrapper version and I'm still getting those issues. Do you want my repo?

Comment: The `build.gradle` may be helpful, along with the stack-trace. Screenshots of errors are not being accepted as debug information and only should be used to show visual issues, which isn't the case.